# CSS3 multiple backgrounds not working

Tags: css, background-image

I am trying to create a simple div with two backgrounds using CSS3. I have created a JS Fiddle with an example of what I'm trying to do here: http://jsfiddle.net/nfcyv/

It is not working, however, and I was hoping somebody could point out why or provide me with a helpful hint.

Below is a copy of the CSS:

```
#box { background:url("http://i.imgur.com/pAmGs.png") no-repeat scroll center bottom #000, url("http://i.imgur.com/fDMpm.png") repeat scroll 0 0 #000;height:500px;width:500px }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only specify a background color for the last layer, so you need to remove the first `#000` from your declaration:

```
#box {
    background:url("http://i.imgur.com/pAmGs.png") no-repeat scroll center bottom, 
               url("http://i.imgur.com/fDMpm.png") repeat scroll 0 0 #000;
    height:500px;
    width:500px
}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/nfcyv/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
#box { 
    background:url("http://i.imgur.com/pAmGs.png") no-repeat center bottom, 
    url("http://i.imgur.com/fDMpm.png") repeat scroll 0 0 #000;
    height:500px;width:500px;
}
```